# Padding to the result of a DISTINCT Sqlite query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I searched and figured out that I could use either `substr` with `||` or a `printf` statement with format specifiers in order to add padding to the results, but that doesn't seem to work if I had `DISTINCT` in the sqlite query.

I've a table called timeLapse that looks like so:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| ID | Time  |  Status   |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | 0.001 | Initiated |
|  1 | 0.002 | Cranked   |
|  3 | 0.002 | Initiated |
|  2 | 0.002 | Initiated |
|  2 | 0.003 | Cranked   |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

I could query the distinct IDs with something like `SELECT distinct(ID) FROM timeLapse as IDs`, which returns this:

```
+-----+
| IDs |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
+-----+
```

However, I would like to pad the resultant distinct rows like so:

```
+----------+
| IDs      |
+----------+
| Object-1 |
| Object-2 |
| Object-3 |
+----------+
```

My query `SELECT substr('Object-' || DISTINCT(ID), 10, 10) as IDs FROM timeLapse` results in an error: 
`"[17:22:47] Error while executing SQL query on database 'machining': near "distinct": syntax error"`

Could someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here? I am enormously thankful for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits to the user named ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ, as I only understood from their answer that I should have a sub-query within this query where the DISTINCT should go into.

This resolves my problem:

```
select printf('Object-%s', t1.ID) as IDs
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(id) ID FROM timeLapse) t1
```

Answer (score 1):

get `distinct()` first before using `substr()` function.

```
select substr('Object-' || t1.ID, 1, 10) as IDs
    from (SELECT DISTINCT(ID) ID FROM timeLapse) t1
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ba4ba/1)

Comment: Thank you for your time. But sorry, that doesn't seem to work. Should the query within the brackets have an "AS" just before the ID? That seems to be missing. But even if I add that, the dbfiddle thing doesn't seem to produce any results. :-(

Comment: @VadaPoché, try dbfiddle i provided, seems working fine

Comment: I visited the dbfiddle thing and clicked Run. It says: `Schema Error: Error: ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE: Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
`

Comment: @VadaPoché, somethings wrong on my dbfidde, i move it to sqlfiddle, try now

Comment: OK, so I see I had to select the correct database (it was MySql earlier), but running the query does not produce the results I'm after. I mean, it just returns 1,2,3 instead of Object-1, Object-2, and so on.

Comment: seems you want to start from 1 on substr(), try now

Comment: Sorry, still not working. It just selects the IDs (which need not be unique btw, it was marked as primary key in your schema). But I want "Object-ID" in the result.

Comment: This seems to work! `select printf('Object-%s', t1.ID) as IDs
    from (SELECT DISTINCT(id) ID FROM node) t1` and is based on your first dbfiddle link.

Comment: @VadaPoché, it think the reason why you use substr() is to limit your characters to 10

Comment: No, my understanding is that in addition to being able to limit the characters, it also helps concatenate two strings using the operator `||`.